# How to select all instances of a widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So does anyone know of a way to 'get' all Labels, for example from a program or window in Tk. i.e like root.winfo.children but only for a type of widget.

Also I know you can use lists, but i want to know if there is a better way?

Comment: Why do you mean by better? What's wrong with lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the universal `winfo_toplevel()` method to get the top-level window containing any widget and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter the class of the items that `winfo_children()` returns so it only contains widgets of the desired type. Here's an example of doing that:

```
from pprint import pprint
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Test', command=self.find_buttons)
        self.quitButton.grid()
        nested_frame = tk.Frame(self)  # Nest some widgets an extra level for testing.
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(nested_frame, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()
        nested_frame.grid()

    def find_buttons(self):
        WIDGET_CLASSNAME = 'Button'
        toplevel = self.winfo_toplevel()  # Get top-level window containing self.
        # Use a list comprehension to filter result.
        selection = [child for child in get_all_children(toplevel)
                        if child.winfo_class() == WIDGET_CLASSNAME]
        pprint(selection)


def get_all_children(widget):
    """ Return a list of all the children, if any, of a given widget.  """
    result = []  # Initialize.
    return _all_children(widget.winfo_children(), result)


def _all_children(children, result):
    """ Recursively append all children of a list of widgets to result. """
    for child in children:
        result.append(child)
        subchildren = child.winfo_children()
        if subchildren:
            _all_children(subchildren, result)

    return result


app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will only return direct descendants. It won't find all Labels in the whole app (unless the whole app has all widgets in the root).

Comment: @Bryan: As usual, good point. I think my updated answer addresses the problem.